# Python3 Sqlite3: how to count the Duplicates items but with omitting a substring from it

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I have a table that contains a column called `Patient` as shown below:

```
Patient
---------
Perez, MD
Perez, MD
Perez, MD
Perez
Perez
Ayoub, MD
Ayoub
.
.
```

and so on ....

I added this query

```
query = "SELECT Patient, COUNT(*) FROM Table GROUP BY Patient ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC"
```

which returns this result:

```
[('Perez, MD', 3), ('Perez', 2), ('Ayoub, MD', 1), ('Ayoub', 1), ......]
```

but I want the proper way to get this result?

```
[('Perez, MD', 5), ('Ayoub, MD', 2), ......]
```

or this:

```
[('Perez', 5), ('Ayoub', 2), ......]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the patient's name contains `,` and if it does extract the left part to use it in the GROUP BY clause:

```
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN INSTR(Patient, ',') = 0 THEN Patient
    ELSE SUBSTR(Patient, 1, INSTR(Patient, ',') - 1)
  END Name, 
  COUNT(*) counter 
FROM tablename 
GROUP BY Name 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Or remove any occurrence of `', MD'`:

```
SELECT 
  REPLACE(Patient, ', MD', '') Name, 
  COUNT(*) counter 
FROM tablename 
GROUP BY Name 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/piWgB68gMYbqa3QxmNFimV/3).
Results:

```
| Name  | counter |
| ----- | ------- |
| Perez | 5       |
| Ayoub | 2       |
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it helped me